# What lifestyle should a MVC controller get when configured in a DI container

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, servicestack

I auto-wire my MVC controllers with the Funq factory, and am curious what lifetime management is like for them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MVC controllers are not designed to be thread-safe since they are initialized by MVC for the request they are handling. So the longest lifestyle they can have is the per-web-request lifestyle. MVC however, will only ask the `IControllerFactory` for a controller once per web request, which means that the controller factory will always return a new controller instance. Picking a per-web-request lifestyle would yield the correct results, but lowers the performance of the system, since there is no need in caching controllers. In other words:

**MVC controllers should have a transient lifestyle.**